# Trimming last character

Tags: php

I know nothing about php, so please excuse the me if this seems obvious to you. Why doesn't  the following code do what I expect it to do:

```
$separator = ', ';
$categories_list = 'Cat1, Cat2';
$exclude_cat = 'Cat2';
$categories_list = rtrim (str_replace( $exclude_cat,  '', $categories_list ), $separator );
if ( $categories_list && $categories_list != '' ) {
    echo '<br/><span class="categories-links">' . $categories_list . '</span>';
```

The result I am getting is `Cat1,`. I expect it to be `Cat1`. Do you see anything wrong with this?

Thank you

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XiFc6x

Comment: It works here, is that space in between perhaps a non-breaking space or a tab in actuality? Best to get all whitespace in there. Also: see [the comments about nbsp's in the manual for `trim()`](http://nl3.php.net/trim) (`\xA0` or `\xC2\xA0`).

Comment: Yeah works for me too just checked..

Comment: I tried to do this: rtrim (trim (str_replace( $exclude_cat,  '', $categories_list )), ',' ). Same result

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, a couple of options here.  What I'd probably do is 'explode' the '$categories_list' into an array, remove the items you don't want and then 'implode' the array back to a string.

```
$categories_array = explode(',', $categories_list);
$hidden_categories = array('Cat2');

foreach ($categories_array AS $category_key => $category_val) {

    if (in_array($category_val, $hidden_categories) {
        unset($categories_array[$category_key]);
    }

}

$categories_list = implode(', ', $categories_array);
```

That way, you can remove as many categories as you want and when you implode them, they will have the correct formatting for displaying.

Another idea is to strip out any characters that you don't want using REGEX.  This is far less flexible than the previous method, but it is a more direct answer to your original question.

```
// REMOVE ANYTHING THAT'S NOT A LETTER OR A NUMBER
$categories_list = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/i', '', $categories_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

trim and arrays would be best in your case, because the trim avoid problems typo making function rtrim and ltrim

PHP and has many functions for the processing of arrays, see an example:

```
<?php
$separator = ',';
$categories_list = 'Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4';

$categories = explode($separator, $categories_list);
$categories = array_filter($categories, 'strlen');//remove blank itens
$categories = array_map('trim', $categories);

$exclude_cat = 'Cat2';

$getKey = array_search($exclude_cat, $categories);
if(false!==$getKey){
    unset($categories[$getKey]);
}

$categories = array_values($categories);

//show with loop
$j = count($categories);
for($i=0; $i<$j; ++$i){
    echo $categories[$i],'<br>';
}

//show with implode
echo implode('<br>', $categories);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your answers. I realized finally why it didn't work (the categories_list has a lot more to it than it writes to the page)...

Comment: You mean there are more than two categories? try my answer!